# jquery append image not rendering in Chrome but does in IE9

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser

I can't seem to get this working in Chrome 22.0, but it works fine in IE 9.0. I am using jquery.min.js version 1.7.1.

File maint.php  (this is a bit simplified...):

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'start') {
    ... do stuff ...
    die;
?>
<html><head><script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<body>
...
<center>
<form name="maint" method="post" action="maint.php">
<input id="action" type="hidden" name="action" value="noop"/>
<input type="button" value="Start" onClick="submitForm('start')"/>
</form>
<div id="workmsg"></div>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(action) {
    $('#workmsg').append('<h3>Please wait...</h3><br/><img src="work2.gif"/>');
    document.getElementById('action').value = action;
    document.maint.submit();
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Clicking the "Start" button displays the message "Please wait..." and shows the work2.gif animation and submits (to itself) where some action is performed, all the while displaying the message and GIF.

Or at least that's how it works on IE9.

On Chrome the message is displayed but the GIF is not.

Any idea why?

Chrome does render the GIF if I browse directly to it.

Comment: did you try inspecting element on the div in chrome? is the img tag added to #workmsg?

Comment: I see no reason why Chrome wouldn't display the image. It worked fine in a jsFiddle when I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is "that old chestnut" that I've come across many times before, change the submit line of code to this...

```
setTimeout(function() { document.maint.submit(); }, 500);
```

You can try shorter timeouts but that should be sufficient, assuming you're having the same problem I've seen before.  The browser may well just need a short time to initialise the image element before the submit is fired.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many times that's been the answer to something annoying ;)